# C# & Fast API WebSocket communication lagging

Tags: python, c#, winforms, websocket, fastapi

I have the following C# client & Fast API host communicating through websocket.

The C# client captures the live webcam frame and sends it to the flask api which then sends it back to the C# client to display in the `PictureBox`.
In this example the Fast API is not doing anything with the image but in the real code the image is being processed, as this is just focusing on the communication between Host and client.

C# (CLIENT):

---

```
private void CaptureCameraCallback(int camInd, PictureBox pictureBox)
        {
            // Create a new WebSocket connection
            using (var ws = new WebSocketSharp.WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/ws"))
            {
                // Connect to the WebSocket server
                ws.Connect();

                // Create a new video capture object
                using (var capture = new VideoCapture(camInd))
                {
                    // Start a loop to capture frames and send them to the Flask API.
                    while (true)
                    {
                        // Create a new Mat object to store the frame
                        using (var frame = new Mat())
                        {
                            // Read the next frame from the camera.
                            capture.Read(frame);

                            // Check if the frame is not empty.
                            if (!frame.Empty())
                            {
                                // Encode the frame as a JPEG image
                                var buffer = new byte[frame.Width * frame.Height * frame.ElemSize()];
                                Cv2.ImEncode(".jpg", frame, out buffer);

                                // Send the image to the server
                                ws.Send(buffer);

                                // Wait for the response from the server
                                ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
                                {
                                    // Convert the response from the server back to an image
                                    var responseBytes = e.RawData;
                                    using (var responseStream = new MemoryStream(responseBytes))
                                    {
                                        var responseImage = Image.FromStream(responseStream);

                                        // Display the response image on the UI thread
                                        pictureBox.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => {
                                            pictureBox.Image = responseImage;
                                        }));
                                    }
                                };
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // If the frame is empty, log an error and continue to the next frame.
                                Debug.WriteLine("Unable to capture Frame");
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

---

FAST API (HOST):

---

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse
import io
import cv2
import numpy as np

class WebSocketServer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = FastAPI()

        @self.app.websocket("/ws")
        async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
            print("Accepting Connection")
            await websocket.accept()
            print('Accepted')
            while True:
                try:
                    image_bytes = await websocket.receive_bytes()
                    nparr = np.frombuffer(image_bytes, np.uint8)
                    img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
                    
                    # Do something with the image here
                    # ...
                    # Send a response back (optional)
                    _, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)
                    response_bytes = buffer.tobytes()
                    await websocket.send_bytes(response_bytes)
                except:
                    pass
                    break
    
    def run(self, host: str = '0.0.0.0', port: int = 8000):
        import uvicorn
        uvicorn.run(self.app, host=host, port=port)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = WebSocketServer()
    server.run()


#uvicorn fastApi:app --reload
```

The image seems to be sent successfully to the Fast API and sent back, but the framerate is extremely slow(less than one FPS). What could I be doing wrong?

I believe maybe I am not processing or displaying the image correctly on the picturebox.

Comment: For sure you don't subscribe to an event in a `while (true)` loop -- You also need to dispose of the Image you have previously set to the PictureBox (it would be better to use an `IProgress<Image>` delegate to perform the update) -- A Timer is probably better than a closed loop for this. The new [PeriodicTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer) could be useful here, if you can use it (.NET 6+)

Comment: Thank you, I am trying all the points you just made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was easily solved by moving the the response from the server, outside of the loop.

Like so:

```
private void CaptureCameraCallback(int camInd, PictureBox pictureBox)
        {
            // Create a new WebSocket connection
            using (var ws = new WebSocketSharp.WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/ws"))
            {
                // Connect to the WebSocket server
                ws.Connect();

                // Create a new video capture object
                using (var capture = new VideoCapture(camInd))
                {
                    // Create a concurrent queue to store response images
                    var responseQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<Image>();

                    // Set up the event handler to add response images to the queue
                    ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        var responseBytes = e.RawData;
                        using var responseStream = new MemoryStream(responseBytes);
                        var responseImage = Image.FromStream(responseStream);
                        responseQueue.Enqueue(responseImage);
                    };

                    // Start a loop to capture frames and send them to the Flask API.
                    while (true)
                    {
                        // Create a new Mat object to store the frame
                        using (var frame = new Mat())
                        {
                            // Read the next frame from the camera.
                            capture.Read(frame);

                            // Check if the frame is not empty.
                            if (!frame.Empty())
                            {
                                // Encode the frame as a JPEG image
                                var buffer = new byte[frame.Width * frame.Height * frame.ElemSize()];
                                Cv2.ImEncode(".jpg", frame, out buffer);

                                // Send the image to the server
                                ws.Send(buffer);

                                // Check if there is a response image in the queue
                                if (responseQueue.TryDequeue(out var responseImage))
                                {
                                    // Display the response image on the UI thread
                                    pictureBox.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
                                    {
                                        pictureBox.Image = responseImage;
                                    }));
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // If the frame is empty, log an error and continue to the next frame.
                                Debug.WriteLine("Unable to capture Frame");
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```